# UIPinchGestureRecognizer doesn't fire after custom UIGestureRecognizer fails

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer, uipinchgesturerecognizer

I have a custom `UIGestureRecognizer` subclass that detects a particular kind of one-finger dragging. On the same scene, I also have a `UIPinchGestureRecognizer`, that detects two-finger pinches.

The problem happens when the user makes a pinch gesture but puts down one finger an instant before the other: the custom gesture recognizer sees a single touch and engages (sets its state to `.began`) and the pinch recognizer doesn't. When the second touch is added, the custom recognizer notices and switches its state to `.failed`. But it's too late and the pinch gesture recognizer doesn't pick it up.

Here's the code for the custom UIGestureRecognizer subclass:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent) {
    super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
    guard touches.count == 1 else {
        state = .failed
        return
    }
    state = .began
}
override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent) {
    super.touchesMoved(touches, with: event)
    guard touches.count == 1 else {
        state = .failed
        return
    }
    // do gesture recognizer stuff here
}

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent) {
    super.touchesEnded(touches, with: event)
    state = .ended
}
```

I've tried it with `cancelsTouchesInView` set to `false` and with `delaysTouchesBegan` set to `true` for the custom gesture recognizer. Neither made a difference in this behavior.

When I use a `UIPinchGestureRecognizer` with a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` I don't have this issue, which leads me to think it's not the intended behavior.

What's wrong with my UIGestureRecognizer fail code and how can I fix it so that a UIPinchGestureRecognizer can still recognize pinches where the touches start non-simultaneously?

Comment: did you find the solution to this?

Comment: @agibson007 Sadly no; my project requirements changed so I didn’t need the custom subclass, and I never bothered to follow up.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` protocol to implement [`gestureRecognizer(_:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uigesturerecognizerdelegate/1624208-gesturerecognizer). That can allow you to have two gestures be recognized simultaneously.

```
class MyVC: UITableViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        let pinchGestureRecognizer = UIPinchGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handlePinchFrom))
        pinchGestureRecognizer.delegate = self
        view.addGestureRecognizer(pinchGestureRecognizer)
    }

    func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```